# How to link another container in Docker that has not been created yet

Tags: networking, docker, hyperlink, containers

I have two servers. Each one must be send some data to the other one. The address of the other server (or servers) is passed as argument (--servers ...).

The problem is that when the container of dmserver0 is created it doesn't find the host "dmserver1" since its container has not been created yet. If I use links then there is an error because of the recursivity.

How could I solve this trouble?

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  dmserver0:
    build: .
    command: nodejs dmserver.js --servers 'tcp://dmserver1:2221'
    container_name: dmserver_0

  dmserver1:
    build: .
    command: nodejs dmserver.js --servers 'tcp://dmserver0:2220'
    container_name: dmserver_1
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:boron

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/forum
WORKDIR /var/www/forum

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libzmq-dev

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

ADD package.json /var/www/forum
RUN npm install

ADD . /var/www/forum
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker can't help you with this. This is an architectural problem in your server applications.

The solution is to modify your server's connection functionality. Instead of exiting on a failed connection you need to enter in a retry loop in both servers.

This will allow both servers to come alive and connect to each other in any arbitrary timespan. This approach has the benefit of being robust and independent of external factors affecting the start-up period.